# Source not add to image in email templage

Tags: php, html

I am creating email template containing some images. I created absolute path of these images and put image in email.

When I checked for email, not found images in email. When I check source of email and found that source of image () is not found there.

I search related this issue but not found any solution about it. Here is sample code.

```
<img src='http://".$_SERVER['HTTP_HOST']."$userPhoto' height=80 width=80 border=1 alt='".$user->getTitle()."'/>
```

When I checked email source code then I got only `<img border="1" width="80" height="80" alt="XYZ">`. Source of image not found here.

Please let me know if any one faced this issue.

Comment: Most likely the image is removed by a spamfilter because it has an unreliable source. Never count on inline images actually getting to the recipient by email.

Comment: I am using zend framework in PHP. Here is a example source of image "http://abc.com/public/group_photo/e4/0d/0dd7_985f.jpg?c=7bcb". Is contain after "?" will affect to image ?

Comment: @Rikesh if he didn't the output would have contained a messed up src value, while it appears to be stripped as a whole.

Comment: Lol, yeah, I'm pretty sure all email clients will strip links to http://localhost/ from incoming emails. Try putting the image on a real webhost - all email clients worth a dime will proactively block any attempts to touch the local computer.

Comment: Am I the only one who thinks the quotation is wrong? Starting with single quotes, then using concat symbol, then double quotes, would it appear like 'http://"blabla/"user_photo.jpg'

Comment: @Niels - Could you please explain in details. I am not getting what you are trying to describe.

Comment: You just edited your comment, before that it said the photo link was to "http://localhost/some/image/url.jpg". That's most certainly not going to work. Is the image hosted on a publicly accessible internet host or not? Spamfilters *will* remove all links to local content, or to untrusted internet hosts.

Comment: @Royal Bg  - I printed email template in browser and it displaying properly. As suggested by Niels, let me test it on live server.

Comment: You say you use the absolute path for the images? To be accessible to the outside world as a url you need hostname (abs path - doc root) - for example if abs path is /usr/home/webdocs/mysite/img/pic.jpg, and your domain (say example.com) is mapped to  /usr/home/webdocs/mysite, you img src should be example.com/img/pic.jpg

Comment: @user602088 - Yes, source of image is like "abc.com/public/group_photo/e4/0d/0dd7_985f.jpg?c=7bcb". I just try it on live server and same issue occurred. When I put image source in browser then it showing image properly. I don't know why this happening. I tired with it.

Comment: Finally, my code is working properly. Thanks all of you guys for giving your valuable time. Thanks a lot.